# shift ArrayBuffer so I can access Float32 values

Tags: javascript, bit-shift, arraybuffer, typed-arrays

I am trying to read a .stl file
the stl file format has the first 80 bytes are a string 
then a float32 that is the number of triangle stored in the file.
then for each triangle 12 float32 values,
then a Uint16 
then the 12 Float32 and 1 Uint16 pattern repeats.

I have been able to get the first triangle values, but I can't read the next array of float32 values out because the offset is not divisible by 4 anymore after getting the Uint16 value. 
Is there any way to do a Left Shift operation on the arraybuffer or some way to continue to read out the values?

Comment: Have you tried using `DataView`?

Comment: yes, I have tried using a DataView and tried copying the array to a new buffer, but I keep getting error's that the length is incorrect or it runs and returns everything as undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pull them out by making a copy

```js
const src = new Uint8Array([1,2,3,4,5,0,0,246,66,0,0,144,64,14,15,16,17,18,19]);
const offset = 5;
const numFloats = 2;
const floats = new Float32Array(src.slice(offset, offset + numFloats * 4).buffer);

console.log(floats);
```

You could also use a [`DataView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView)

```js
const src = new Uint8Array([1,2,3,4,5,0,0,246,66,0,0,144,64,14,15,16,17,18,19]);
const offset = 5;
const dataview = new DataView(src.buffer);
const littleEndian = true;

console.log(dataview.getFloat32(offset, littleEndian));
console.log(dataview.getFloat32(offset + 4, littleEndian));
```

Comment: The slice method was one I had tried but I was only setting the (numFloats * 4) and not (offset + numFloats * 4). making this change got this working for me. 
Thanks

Comment: I made the same mistake when first writing the example 